# I want to replace missing values based on some conditions in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The following is the dataset I'm working on

[image: Dataset]

As you can see there are some missing values (NaN) which need to be replaced, on certain conditions:

1. If Solar.R < 50 then the missing value of Ozone needs to be replaced by the value = 30.166667
2. If Solar.R < 100 then the missing value of Ozone needs to be replaced by the value = 21.181818
3. If Solar.R < 150 then the missing value of Ozone needs to be replaced by the value = 53. 13043
4. If Solar.R < 200 then the missing value of Ozone needs to be replaced by the value = 59. 840000
5. If Solar.R < 250 then the missing value of Ozone needs to be replaced by the value = 59. 840000
6. If Solar.R < 300 then the missing value of Ozone needs to be replaced by the value = 50. 115385
7. If Solar.R < 350 then the missing value of Ozone needs to be replaced by the value = 26. 571429

Is there any way to do this using pandas and if-else? I've tried using loc() but it resulted in the non - NaN values getting modified too.

PS: This is the code using loc()

```
while (s['Ozone'].isna() == True):
    s.loc[(s['Solar.R'] < 50), 'Ozone'] = '30.166667'
    s.loc[(s['Solar.R'] < 100), 'Ozone'] = '21.181818'
    s.loc[(s['Solar.R'] < 150), 'Ozone'] = '53.13043'
    s.loc[(s['Solar.R'] < 200), 'Ozone'] = '59.840000'
    s.loc[(s['Solar.R'] < 250), 'Ozone'] = '59.840000'
    s.loc[(s['Solar.R'] < 300), 'Ozone'] = '50.115385'
    s.loc[(s['Solar.R'] < 350), 'Ozone'] = '26.571429'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your conditions are linear, you can use `floordiv` to select the right values for `Ozone` column and `mask` to hide other values:

```
values = [30.166667, 21.181818, 53.13043, 59.840000,
          59.840000, 50.115385, 26.571429]
s['Ozone'] = s.mask(~s['Solar.R'].between(0, 350))['Solar.R'] \
              .sub(1).floordiv(50).map(pd.Series(values))
print(s)

# Output:
    Solar.R      Ozone
0      50.0  30.166667
1       NaN        NaN
2     450.0        NaN
3      98.0  21.181818
4     348.0  26.571429
5     302.0  26.571429
6     348.0  26.571429
7     279.0  50.115385
8       8.0  30.166667
9      80.0  21.181818
10    140.0  53.130430
11    239.0  59.840000
12    227.0  59.840000
13     93.0  21.181818
14    305.0  26.571429
15     80.0  21.181818
16    104.0  53.130430
17    180.0  59.840000
18    179.0  59.840000
19     59.0  21.181818
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
common = df['col_2'].isnull()
all_conditions = [(df['Solar.R'] < 50) & (common),
                  (df['Solar.R'] > 50) & (df['Solar.R'] < 100) & (common),
                  (df['Solar.R'] > 100) & (df['Solar.R'] < 150) & (common),
                  (df['Solar.R'] > 150) & (df['Solar.R'] < 250) & (common),
                  (df['Solar.R'] > 250) & (df['Solar.R'] < 300) & (common),
                  (df['Solar.R'] > 300) & (df['Solar.R'] < 350) & (common)]

fill_with = ['30.166667', '21.181818', '53.13043', '59.840000', '50.115385', '26.571429']
df['col_2'] = np.select(all_conditions, fill_with, default=df['col_2'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pd.cut()` to bin the Solar.R values and assign Ozone values to each of the bins, and then use the resulting values in `fillna()`.

I use the example data provided in another answer by @Marcello.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Example dataset with values for each interval - @Marcello.
example = {'Solar.R' : [25, 25, 87, 87, 134, 134, 187, 187, 234, 234, 267, 267, 345, 345],
           'Ozone' : [1, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1, np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(example)

# Find rows with missing data.
fill_needed = df["Ozone"].isna()

# In those rows only, put Solar.R into bins, labelled with values for Ozone.
fill_values = pd.cut(df["Solar.R"][fill_needed],
                     [0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350],
                     labels=[30.166667, 21.181818, 53.13043,
                             59.840000, 59.840000, 50.115385,
                             26.571429],
                     ordered=False).astype(float)

# Put the fill values into the holes in the Ozone series.
df["Ozone"].fillna(fill_values, inplace=True)
df

#     Solar.R      Ozone
# 0        25   1.000000
# 1        25  30.166667
# 2        87   1.000000
# 3        87  21.181818
# 4       134   1.000000
# 5       134  53.130430
# 6       187   1.000000
# 7       187  59.840000
# 8       234   1.000000
# 9       234  59.840000
# 10      267   1.000000
# 11      267  50.115385
# 12      345   1.000000
# 13      345  26.571429
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `.fillna(value)` can be used. It only changes the `NaN` values in a dataframe and not other values. Here is an example for your specific problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#example dataset with values for each interval
example = {'Solar.R' : [25, 25, 87, 87, 134, 134, 187, 187, 234, 234, 267, 267, 345, 345],
           'Ozone' : [1, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1, np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(example)

#list of pairs of the cutoff and the respective values
#!!! needs to be sorted from smallest cutoff to largest
cut_off_values = [(50, 30.166667), (100, 21.181818), (150, 53.13043),
                  (200, 59.840000), (250, 59.840000), (300, 50.115385), 
                  (350, 26.571429)]

#iterate the list of pairs and change only the nan values
for pair in cut_off_values:
    df[df['Solar.R'] < pair[0]] = df[df['Solar.R'] < pair[0]].fillna(pair[1])

print(df.to_string())
```

**Output:**

```
    Solar.R      Ozone
0        25   1.000000
1        25  30.166667
2        87   1.000000
3        87  21.181818
4       134   1.000000
5       134  53.130430
6       187   1.000000
7       187  59.840000
8       234   1.000000
9       234  59.840000
10      267   1.000000
11      267  50.115385
12      345   1.000000
13      345  26.571429
```